# Int array and IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I declare int array in SQL Server?

After fill it, I would like to use it in IN statement to check, how can I change my code?

```
declare @mode int =1 
declare @acceptedFormTypeIds table (id int)

case @mode
    when 1 then
        insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (1, 2, 3, 4)
    when 2 then 
        insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (1, 3)
    when 3 then 
        insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (2, 4)
    else
        insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (1, 2, 3, 4)
end

...

WHERE
    tFRM.SendDate between @datefrom and @dateto
    and tFRM.TemplateId IN @acceptedFormTypeIds.id
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In databases, don't ever think of arrays. Think of sets, or tables.

The structure of the insert statement should be

```
insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (1), (2), (3), (4)
```

You can use `if`

```
if @mode=2
begin
   insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (1), (3)
end
else
begin
    if @mode=3
    begin
       insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (2), (4)
    end
    else
    begin
       insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (1), (2), (3), (4)
    end
end
```

However, it may be worth having a `FormTypeModeAccepted` table depending on your usage.

Answer (score 4):

There is no switch-like statement, the `case` is an expression, so you would use `if`.

To insert multiple records, you use `values (2), (4)` instead of `values (2, 4)`.

When using the table in `in`, you need to select from it.

```
declare @mode int = 1
declare @acceptedFormTypeIds table (id int)

if (@mode = 1) begin
  insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (1), (2), (3), (4)
end else if (@mode = 2) begin 
  insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (1), (3)
end else if (@mode = 3) begin 
  insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (2), (4)
end else begin
  insert into @acceptedFormTypeIds(id) values (1), (2), (3), (4)
end

...    
WHERE
    tFRM.SendDate between @datefrom and @dateto
    and tFRM.TemplateId IN (select id from @acceptedFormTypeIds)
```

Comment: *You can't use value to add multiple records*?? Perhaps not in earlier versions of SQL-Server, but it has been a feature since at least 2008.

Answer (score 2):

To switch statements you need to use `IF` rather than `CASE`, you also need to put each value to insert in it's own parentheses.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @mode INT = 1;
DECLARE @acceptedFormTypeIds TABLE (id INT);

IF @mode = 1
    INSERT @acceptedFormTypeIds (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);
ELSE IF @mode = 2
    INSERT @acceptedFormTypeIds (id) VALUES (1), (3);
ELSE IF @mode = 2
    INSERT @acceptedFormTypeIds (id) VALUES (2), (4);
ELSE 
    INSERT @acceptedFormTypeIds (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4);


SELECT  *
FROM    @acceptedFormTypeIds;
```